# Can't Open App After Installing From Google Play

Tags: google-play-services, developer-console

My application i cant open it from google play, even test from another device, its same isuue.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- i faced same issue when i was beginner in Android studio.
- its look like you missed something in your app Manifets.
  , Make sure you add all (activity/permission's) in Manifets.xml
  if not work let us know more.

in the end dont forget to (update/upgrade) your new version in google play.

Comment: you right, i was missed activity's in manifets. i able to open application rn. 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPfqQ.jpg)